# Warning: DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php on line 273

Tags: magento2

I am using Magento latest release 2.x.

Everything works fine, except when saving a product with an image Magento 2.x throws an error

> Warning: DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php on line 273

I have just started learning Magento. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm having same issue... perhaps you should post your question to http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 17):

Though it is old question, there is no answer in 5 months. I got similar issue and found the cause for my case.

This issue might be generated due to wrong XML configuration. If you would add more code related to this issue, I probably could isolate the exact reason behind this issue.

At my end, I wrote di.xml wrongly, I didn't write  root tag in di.xml. For that reason, this error would generate.

If anybody gets this issue, you should check your configuration files.

Comment: That was exactly the cause of my problem: copy/pasting from posts missing the obvious parts.

Comment: Great finding Agilox , I wish Magento displayed a better error!

Answer (score 2):

The Main Problem Is your command line Is not Working...

And A Firstly Check Your Configuration File Before Not working any Idea Then Do this

This is Create an issue in Di.Xml File If you are only changing a Di.xml File Name Then Problem Solved

Answer (score 0):

change current mode to developer and see the file which generating the error.

Comment: This is a helpful comment, but probably shouldn't be considered an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I missed to add the headers `<config>` of the di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
```